# Issue with Permission Set Groups being unassigned after user creation via OKTA in Salesforce

Tags: licenses, cpq, permission-set-groups, okta, permission-set-assignment

I need assistance in identifying the cause of an issue related to **Permission Set Groups** in Salesforce when creating a user via **OKTA**.

Our automation on the **User** SObject correctly assigns **Permission Set Licenses** and **Permission Set Groups** based on the **CPQ Access** field value. However, when an admin creates a user through OKTA, we observe an anomaly. After the initial assignment of permission set licenses and permission set groups, the permission set groups are unexpectedly unassigned (Audit Trails are provided as evidence).
[image]

The debug logs only show the correct transaction where the permission set licenses and permission set groups are inserted, with no logs indicating any deletions.

We have also reviewed the OKTA actions for this operation, and the system log events indicate successful user creation and synchronization with the external application (attached screenshot).
[image]

In summary, we are unable to determine the cause of the unassignment of permission set groups following their successful assignment. We have reached out to OKTA support and opened a case to inquire about obtaining the full body of the request from OKTA to Salesforce during user provisioning.

If any of you have experience with OKTA or have encountered similar behaviour, your insights would be greatly appreciated.